# How to configure CloudFront to route request to load balancer or S3 depending on path prefix?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

My backend server is behind an ELB while my static files are behind S3. I want to route requests based on path prefix:

- `/admin`: (admin CMS) Goes to ELB
- `/v1`: (API) Goes to ELB too
- Anything else: S3

How can I achieve this?

I set it up like:

[image]

My ELB origin is setup with an empty Origin Path. Is that correct? Or do I need to put `/admin`/`/v1` there?

In any case, after setting up origin/behaviour, when I try to access `/admin` I get an error `X-Cache:Error from cloudfront`. What did I configure wrongly?

I also notice the response header `Server:AmazonS3`, it appears the path pattern is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found I made a few mistakes

- I need to wait until the distribution status is deployed
- Also the path patterns should contain a trailing `/*` eg. `/admin/*` unless I want to match exactly eg. `/admin`